# How to add keyword to FROM clause of ActiveRecord query

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, rails-activerecord

I am using PostgreSQL's [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-inherit.html) feature to model my data and I need to use the `ONLY` keyword in queries in certain ActiveRecord models. For example, I want `Shift.all` to invoke `SELECT shifts.* FROM ONLY shifts`. Otherwise, it will also return results from the child `assigned_shifts` table.

As far as I can tell, there is no easy configurable way to do this. I've tried `set.table_name = 'ONLY shifts'` on the ActiveRecord model but that creates an error because it adds `'ONLY shifts'.*` to the `SELECT` statement.

Is there a way to monkey-patch Arel or ActiveRecord to build the query I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

For posterity:

```
class Shifts < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope -> { from("ONLY shifts") }
end
```